# How to read attributes msRTCSIP-UserPolicy and msExchRecepientTypeDetails in C#

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to read the values of the user object. I am not sure how to read the values for the following attributes msRTCSIP-UserPolicy and msExchRecepientTypeDetails
in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) The following link gives on method of reading msRTCSIP-UserPolicy using VB or Pearl. However, when I tried to use that method in C#, it did not work. I must mention that I do not know VB and I might have done something wrong.
http://www.itadmintools.com/2010/07/msrtcsip-userpolicy-heres-how-to-read.html#comment-form

(2) I was able to figure out the solution for msExchRecepientTypeDetails and I am giving below the code if anyone is interested.

long m_Test = LongFromLargeInteger(p_InputValue);

```
  String  m_ReturnValue = m_Test.ToString();
```

public static long LongFromLargeInteger(object largeInteger)

```
    {
        System.Type type = largeInteger.GetType();
        int highPart = (int)type.InvokeMember("HighPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null,      largeInteger, null);
        int lowPart = (int)type.InvokeMember("LowPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, largeInteger, null);

        return (long)highPart << 32 | (uint)lowPart;
    }//end of method LongFromLargeInteger
```

OK. Finally, I was able to figure out a solution for reading msRTCSIP-UserPolicy also today. The Code is given below:
                      ActiveDs.IADsDNWithBinary dnWithBinary;
                      dnWithBinary = (ActiveDs.IADsDNWithBinary)p_InputValue;

```
                  String m_PolicyDN = dnWithBinary.DNString;
                  Byte[] m_BinaryArray = (byte[]) dnWithBinary.BinaryValue;
                  String m_Value1 =String.Empty;


                  string hexString = string.Empty;

//Convert the ByteArray to Hex
 for (int i = 0; i < m_BinaryArray.Length; i++)
      {                        
        hexString += m_BinaryArra[i].ToString("X2");     

      }//end of loop
```

String m_ReturnValue = "B:8:" + hexString + ":" +m_PolicyDN;

Comment: OK. Finally, I was able to figure out a solution for (1) above. The Code is given below: